# What is the best strategy to solve such problems. $f(x)=3x+5$ what is $f(\frac{1-x}{x})$?

Tags: functions

I have been facing with problems like these;

#### 1. $f(x)=3x+5$ what is $f(\frac{1-x}{x})$?

#### 2. For $f$ function that provides $f(2x)=3x$ find $f(0)$, $f(\frac{1}{2})$ and $f(\frac{2}{3})$.

What is the best strategy to find answers to such problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hint for $1$.

If all the various $x$'s confuse you, rewrite as $$f(\star) =3 \star + 5 $$
Now substitute $\star = \cfrac{1-x}{x}$ and simplify the equation.

---

For $2$ notice that:

$f(0) = f(2*0)$

$f(\frac12) = f(2*\frac14)$

$f(\frac23) = f(2*\frac13)$

Comment: I was looking back through my old questions on Math SE and I saw this question had no accepted answer. Your answer fits very well with my old questions. I kept improvong over 2 years and I'm learning more stuff. I really forgot that I was having troubles with these kind of problems. Glad people here are very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach for the second type of problem is the one that follows. Take $f(2x) = 3x$. If we set $2x = y$ then, $x = y/2$, from which it follows that $$f(y) = 3\frac{y}{2}.$$ Now, because $x$ and $y$ are dummy variables, we can recover $f(x)$ putting $$f(x) = \frac{3}{2}x$$

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand the tip for the first question. Can you help me about it please?